# Por que o IDE Netbeans não deleta automaticamente o Build de uma aplicação java web que foi importada?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

Baixei um projeto java web e importei para o `netbeans`,quando todo o importado projeto com todas as bibliotecas suas estavam no seu devido lugar, juntamente com o arquivo `web.xml`(dentro de WEB-INF), executei o  projeto e ele iniciou o `tomcat` e no browser o aplicativo funcionou de forma satisfatória!Até ai tudo bem! Mas  quando tento limpar e construir o projeto na `IDE` `netbeans` ela indica um  erro dizendo que não pode deletar o diretório `build`!!

O projeto respeitava a hierarquia de pastas de uma aplicação  web, como ilustra a figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A abaixo segue o `erro` que  IDE informa:**

Deleting directory C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Projetos\SimpleJspServletDB-master\build
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Projetos\SimpleJspServletDB-master\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1439: Unable to delete file   C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Projetos\SimpleJspServletDB-master\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\db.properties
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 6 segundos)

Comment: Só posso deletar manualmente ,mas para isso tenho que  fechar o Ide !! Ai quando abro  ide e mando limpar e construir ele faz sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Não é questão de permissão? edite a pergunta e coloque a mensagem de erro.

Comment: rray ,Descobri qual o erro , era o descritor da aplicação, o arquivo web.xml. Editei apenas ele e tudo deu certo!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vezes quando se baixa um exemplo da internet para o aprendizado você pode topar com uma versão antiga de código para a sua IDE e com isso podem acontecer alguns conflitos.É sempre bom dar uma olhada no codigo para observar as versões de arquivos usadas no arquivo web.xml e compará-las com as atuais que você esta usando no seu contêiner(no meu caso o TOMCAT)!!

O problema é o descritor web.xml. Não consegue limpar e construir de forma automatica com o IDE porque o cabeçalho do arquivo web.xml (descritor da aplicação) que veio com o projeto esta errado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

**SUBSTITUIR POR**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"  version="3.1">
```